# Proof that a codimension one subvariety has one local equation on Shafarevich's book.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

I'm following the proof on Shafarevich's book Basic Algebraic Geometry I of this theorem

> *Theorem 2.10* An irreducible subvariety $Y ⊂ X$ of codimension 1 has a local equation
>   in a neighbourhood of any nonsingular point $x ∈ X$.

Another way of stating this is that the image of the ideal $I(Y)$ in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is principal.

The proof is reduced to the case in which $X$ is affine and the first part proceed as follows:

> Let $f \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ be any function that vanishes on $Y$. Factorise $f$ into prime factors in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. By the irreducibility of $Y$ , one factor must also vanish on
>   $Y$ . We denote this by $g$, and prove that it is a local equation of $Y$ . Replacing $X$ by a
>   smaller affine neighbourhood of $x$, we can assume that $g$ is regular on $X$.
>   Since $V (g) ⊃ Y$ , and both are codimension 1 subvarieties, we have $V (g) = Y \cup Y'$. If $x \in Y'$ there exist functions $h$ and $h'$ such that $hh'
>  = 0$ on $V (g)$, but neither $h$ nor $h'$ are $0$ on $V (g)$. [...]

I'm failing to see where $h$ and $h'$ are coming from and how they depend on the assumption that $x \in Y'$. How would I define them?

Comment: Maybe you should use the reducibility of $Y\cup Y'$ : $h$ vanishes on $Y$ and not on $Y'$ and vice-versa.

Comment: Maybe, but why would I require $x \in Y'$ then? What I have thought was that $g = h/h'$ with $h, h' \in k[X]$ and $h'(x) \neq 0 $, then $h'$ wouldn't vanish on $Y'$, but on this case $h$ would vanish on the whole $V(g)$ wouldn't it?